# Car Skeleton for game (Interior)

Tags: unity

I'm making a car for my Unity 5 game. I've already made all the interior. I want to make some animations like open-close door, open the window with rotating handle, open the hood and so on.

All the static parts are combined together in one mesh; all moveable parts are separated by meshes.

My thoughts are: attach bones to each mesh, and animate them. But I think it's not the best choice from architecture side, what if I attach all my static and dynamic meshes together, and then animate them like a regular skeleton? Then my question is: how to attach weights for each bone, so my car will stay solid?

Comment: When you parent the bones to the meshes, use Ctrl-P > Bone to parent them. This will leave the meshes unweighted, so no deformities will occur.

Comment: I think there is no need in skeleton at all. The car movements itself are too simple.

Comment: Whatever floats your boat.